# Unable to deploy rails app to heroku (Could not detect rake tasks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, bootsnap

I'm having this error when i'm trying to deploy to Heroku:

`Could not detect rake tasks, ensure you can run $ bundle exec rake -P against your app and using the production group of your Gemfile. cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)`

Rails 5.4.4.2
Ruby 2.6.3
Bootsnap 1.7.0
Heroku Stack 18

Comment: Can you run that command locally? And could you past in your Gemfile?

Comment: @Msencenb `bundle exec rake -P` jsut list the aviable tasks

Answer (score 1):

ok, solved by using bundler 1.17.2 instead of 2.2.8